# String : Data Type or Data Structure?

Tags: string, data-structures, types, computer-science

A string can be considered as an array of characters. Right? Then why string is considered as a data type in so many languages and not a data structure ?

I was thinking in terms of data structures but then was confused about strings being a data type

Comment: It is both. A data type is an interface. A data structure is an implementation.